# Overnight Batch Processing - Inline Application Code Vs Transact SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, inline-code

The debate over the use of inline code vs stored procedures pretty much always centres around simple CRUD operations and whether to call stored procedures or use inline SQL in a live application.  However, it is also common for companies such as banks, hedge funds and insurance companies to do batch processing which is scheduled to occur after hours.  These are not simple CRUD operations, we're talking about often transactional, specialised business logic.  One example might be the calculation daily compounded interest.

The process needs to be efficient and scalable due to the volume of records to be processed.  By processing overnight, the batches can utilise resources that would not be available to it during the day.

It is no surprise to me that this kind of logic is often implemented in the back-end using something like stored procedures in SQL server or its equivalent on other platforms.  I would expect such an implementation to always be more efficient than inline code, even if that inline code was implemented as a service running on the database server (without network latency).

The TSQL implementation benefits from compiled query execution plans and does not have to parse data between processes via a connection.

Am I wrong about this?  I would like to hear from people with experience in this area.  Anyone who believes a back-end implementation means writing inline code via cursors in stored procedures need not comment.

Comment: I like implementations such as nightly batches in stored procedures. We designed something like this: The whole batch is ONE stored procedure which executes X "child-procedures" . So you can easily work with transactions, try-catch blocks,... so that your batch stops if he should (maybe error occured) and goes on in case of errors to be ignored. What's more we logged every step in a logtable with information about start-time, end-time, success or error,....

Comment: all of this could also be done in SSIS - it offers transactions, precedence constraints,... but as database developer a stored procedure is easier to maintain  - my opinion

Comment: What would you say to someone who claimed that in an object oriented implementation you'd increase code re-use, encapsulation and benefit from unit testing?  And the same person flatly denied that there was any performance benefit to running in TSQL.

Comment: code re-use and encapsulation is possible in sql as well. we use SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) in Visual Studio to design our database projects. There you have all the benefits of Visual Studio (Source Control, Deployment, Builds,..) as if you design any other project type. What's more: for big transactions or heavy calculations there is NOTHING that performs like a well designed server side stored procedure.

Comment: Just test it - stored procedure vs hibernate or whatever...results will be clear i think since there is no network or framework overhead in a stored procedure

Comment: I am considering running an experiment. Just wanted to source some opinions first.  I agree with you wholeheartedly that it will perform better.  I honestly don't understand how anyone can think it wouldn't, but I am being challenged nonetheless.  I will take a look at SSDT.  Thanks for your input, it was very helpful.

Comment: you're welcome! believe me in know your situation, and endless discussions from my own experience